# GUI for Python, Spark and R

Tags: python, gui, r

We have a SAS Enterprise guide as GUI for SAS. Similarly we would like have a GUI for Python and Spark. Can any one suggest GUI's for Python and Spark?

Thanks

Comment: Strictly SAS-EG is a point-and-click, menu- and wizard-driven tool for developing data queries rather than a GUI - it is more like a studio or mathcad type builder solution.

Comment: What kind of application do you want to develop in Python? Will you develop a command-line tool, or a UI?

Comment: We would like to use either Python or Spark for Data transformations and cleaning. We are looking for list of tools we can use for This purpose. We can use Pycharm/Jupiter Notebook/Zepplin for cleaning and transformations. I am just checking whether we have a tool like SAS EG for data related queries.

Answer (score 2):

RStudio has stylesheets for python and spark scripting and R has packages for calling python and sparkly (rpython, sparklyr) so I guess you could use the RStudio IDE.

It has areas to control objects, view output, write scripts, git integration, file browser. And you can save projects in neat packages along with your data using .RProj.

Comment: I am using the Jupyter notebook now. I will give a try to RStudio also. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

For Python, I use and recommend [Spyder](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder). It sort of mimics MATLAB's GUI. Although the normal techniques work, for scientific/statistical/data science uses, I recommend installing using [Anaconda](https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/). This [page](http://certosaconsulting.com/articles/introduction-to-apache-spark/) describes using Spyder with Spark.

[image]

Another GUI for Python that I've played with is [Rodeo](https://www.yhat.com/products/rodeo). It looks promising, but I've spent very little time with it. There seems to be some integration available with Spark as described [here](http://blog.yhat.com/posts/rodeo-0.4.html) and [here](https://mingchen0919.github.io/learning-apache-spark/pyspark-on-rodeo.html).

[image]