# Python 3 GUI libary

Tags: python

I am looking for a Python GUI library, *Not a software.*

I want to create a roleplay game, with a text output, and a Entry field, where users can give his commands.
But Tkinter does not work me, it's not for that purpose.

What library can I for this purpose?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GUI for Python, Spark and R](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/39764/gui-for-python-spark-and-r)

Comment: No, because I ask about a library, not a GUI creator.

Answer (score 1):

Hello and welcome to the community.

GTK+, PyQt (Qt) would be popular options. For a complete list please refer to https://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming